# How to set up render layers for large project

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes, color, render-layers

I am working on my biggest project yet, it’s a video of the Falcon 9 rocket launching and landing from a launch pad.  It’s around 4500 frames long.  How would a professional animator split up the render layers? Do I render everything in the scene on one image or do I split up smoke then split rocket then split the rest in separate layers for composting and color grating?  How would a professional go about this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: The point is for it to look right. If doing it all in one layer looks right I would do that. Professional just means they’ve been ‘round the block more than the average joe. Try rendering a few intervalled frames and see if they look alright.

Comment: Thanks, will do